# Vista CPRS CONNECTion WITh MIRTH AND THEN USING MIRTH I WANT TO GET SELECTED PATIENT DATA FROM CPRS

Tags: xml, mirth, ccd

I have Installed Intersystems Cache Database for Impementing 
WorldVistA EHR  2.0
Now I want To connect This Cache Databse with Our EHR.DAT FILE.

I am tring to get extract patients data from cprs in HL7 Format  but there is only print option .

Pls Guide Me how can I solve this ,any help is appriciable.